# Modded mc server not booting up, Reason unknown

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So Im having an issue booting up a modded mc server installation using forge 1.12.2.
The reason is unknown but I've had this issue before. All I've heard was to reinstall Java, even though I have done that multiple times.

Here is what my directory looks like:

[image: Server directory screenshot]

This is stored inside `c:desktop/server`. Here is the server boot code: `java -Xmx1024M -jar forge-universal.jar nogui`.

Here is the error, I cannot understand what any of it means, and there is no offical minecraft crash log:

```
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:70)
        at net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.<init>(Launch.java:34)
        at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: What is your Java Version? You can get it through `java -version`

Comment: Java 16.0.2, but as I commented under Elikill58's reply this does not seem to be the issue. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be on Java 16. You can check with `java -version`.

Forge 1.12 can't be runned with this version of Java. So, I suggest you to :

- Install older version such as Java 8.
- Change boot code to `C:\Dir\To\Jre\java.exe -Xmx1024M -jar forge-universal.jar nogui`
- OR change `JAVA_PATH` variable to the Java 8 JRE instead of Java 16's one.

Comment: Hmm this seems to be so, but using MCSS soft, I found through console that forge was unable to install some of the required libraries, leading me to belive that my antivirus was blocking the connection to this software. This is proven true by the fact that I am unable to visit https://files.minecraftforge.net

Comment: Try to disable your antivirus temporary to be sure. But MCForge.net is a good site, it's bad antivirus if it block it....

Comment: It's Norton family, obviously, it's bad. I will ask to get it unblocked for sure

Comment: You know, basic Windows Defender is better than lot of antivirus, because it's made directly on the internal OS. Personnally, I don't have any antivirus and any virus too

Comment: Eh its more of parental control then an antivirus

Comment: I will get back to this question as soon as I disable my antivirus, in about 30 or so minutes.

Comment: This seems like the most likely explanation, I should probably just stick with Forge 1.16.5 for this version of java

Comment: Didnt work, guess will have to try something else now.

Comment: With forge 1.12 and Java 8 it didn't work ?

Comment: I havent tried forge 1.12.2 with java 8, Ill have to install docker and try that

Comment: Ok but if you do `java -version` it's already java 16 ? And did you well change the java path ?

Comment: yes *java -version* yeilds 16.0.2